# PHP7.1 has been installed but php -v still show PHP5.6

Tags: 16.04, php

I've been installed PHP7.1 and my on my laptop has 2 php versions there are 
PHP 5.6 and PHP7.1 , i tried `a2dismod php5.6` and `a2enmod php7.1` then i restarted .. and i tried `php -v` still show me old version , anyone have solution about this ?

Thank you

[image]

Comment: Please install the `cli` version of php7.1

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Instead, copy the text here and apply code formatting.

Comment: Also make sure to restart the server so the changes take effect!

Answer (score 2):

That version has to do with the `cli` (command-line interpreter) version which you might not have installed so install it:

```
sudo apt install php7.1-cli
```

then check that version again. Noe remove the other version:

```
sudo apt remove php5.6-cli
```

if that is what it's called, then restart you server.

Comment: already installed sir but still didn't work ...

Comment: Did you remove the old version?

Comment: i tried `php7.1 --version` is work but `Codeigniter 4` said required php7 ... even though php7.1 is enable on my laptop right now ... any solution ?

Comment: What version of php7 does it need perhpas it's php7.2?

Comment: no, Ci4 required 7 or higher ... see it : https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4

Comment: Any ways that's a different question all together! If this worked for the title of the post then accept and post another question. Ther are other things required there are all installed?

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen for me it seems that OP can switch PHP version with `update-alternatives --config php` (or similar command, I hope you got the idea).

Comment: Ah! Didn't knwo this only use it with `java` installs. Should investigate the potentials of update-alternatives! Thanks for the HUP!

Answer (score -2):

a2dismod is a command that disables php support for apache service.
On the other hand, php-cli package is only meant to work for console (in terminal).
Unless you uninstall php-cli package (or php7.1-cli for 7.1 version) you will be able to work with php in terminal (even it won't work on your webservice at the time)

If you want to replace php 5.6 with 7.1 in the cli do this:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/php
ln -s /usr/bin/php7.1 /usr/bin/php
```

this should replace your current cli version with 7.1 and `php -v` should show your desired version

Comment: already installed sir but still didn't work ...

Comment: see my updated answer

Comment: Removing binaries by hand is completely bad idea! They are maintained by APT, and should be removed from it! Moreover `update-alternatives --config php` will change symlinks for this case.

Comment: @N0rbert he's using the PPA, and the usr/bin/php is not binary anyway, it's also a symlink to /etc/alternatives/php which you can confirm with `ls -al /usr/bin | grep php`

Comment: [ SOLVED ] Thank you guys .... i have 2 php versions on my laptop ... so i just do like this `php7.2 -v` run spark codeigniter : `php7.2 spark serve`